# Git says I am ahead by 2 commits but it seems to be 1

Tags: git, branch

Please check my commit tree with local and remote master branches on the screenshot. Why is this "Ahead by 2 commits"? It seems to me that master is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit.

Meanwhile it is ahead by 2 commits from the point they diverged.

What am I thinking wrong?

[image]

Comment: Specifically it is the first commit, with `master` and `HEAD`, as well as the commit almost at the bottom, the 3rd from the bottom. These two are not (yet) on `origin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is ahead of `B` by n commits. It means the n commits are reachable from A and not from B. Or we can say they are on `A` but not on `B`.

`git log origin/master..master` returns the 2 commits. They are reachable from `master` and not from `origin/master`, so `master` is ahead of `origin/master` by 2 commits.